# Assume each $a_{ij}\ge 0$ and $\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}=A$ , can we have $\sum_i \sum_j a_{i,j}=A$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Assume $a_{i,j} \ge 0$ , if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j}$ converges to $A_j$ for each $j$ and $\sum_j A_j$ converges , then we have $$\sum_i\sum_j a_{i,j}=\sum_j \sum_i a_{i,j}$$
>   Moreover , if $p$ is a one-to-one correspondence from $N \to (N,N)$ , then we have $$\sum_n a_{p(n)}=A$$

However , what about the converse of the theorem ?
Assume $a_n \ge 0$ , if $\sum_n a_n=A$ and $q$ is a one-to-one correspondence from $(N,N) \to N$ . Can we have $$\sum_i \sum_j a_{q(i,j)}=A$$ ?

**My attempt:**
$(1)$ We have $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_{q(i,j)}=A$$
Since for each $N$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_{q(i,j)} \le A$ and for all $k \lt K$ we can find an $N$ such that all of $a_k$ belongs to $\{p(i,j)| i,j \le N \}$ , so $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_{q(i,j)} \ge \sum_{i=1}^K a_i$ for each $K$ .

$(2)$ Let $A_i=\sum_j a_{q(i,j)}$ , then obviously $A_i \le A$ .If we can show $\sum_i A_i$ converges to $B$ , let $b_{i,j}=a_{q(i,j)}$ then by the above theorem  we have $$\sum_n a_n= \sum_n b_{q^{-1}(n)}=B$$ which implies $A=B$ .

**My question :**
Although each $A_i$ is finite , how can we prove that $\sum_i A_i$ is finite ?

Comment: In the title, you have $a_{ij}\ge0$; in the body, you don't. Please edit for consistency, so we know which you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it , each $a_{i,j}$ might be greater than $0$ .